# New dynamic variable in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can dynamic variables in C# 4.0 be members on a class or passed into or returned from methods? var from C# 3.0 couldn't but I haven't seen any mention anywhere of whether it is possible or not with dynamic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the above. I tried them out in the VPC and was able to do all of these. See the ['New Features in C#' document here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfuture)

Answer (score 6):

Yes. There's a big difference between `var` and `dynamic`.

`var` just means "let the compiler infer the real type of the variable".

`dynamic` *is* the type of the variable - so anywhere you can specify a type, you can specify `dynamic` instead, as I understand it. (I'm sure there are some exceptions to this, but that's the basic idea.)

EDIT: Chris Burrow's [first blog entry on `dynamic`](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/10/27/c-dynamic.aspx) (there's a [second one](http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/10/28/c-dynamic-part-ii.aspx) already; expect more soon) gives an example class which uses `dynamic` all over the place.

Comment: Actually dynamic isn't *really* the type. It more just says, don't determine the actual type until runtime. You can use "is" on dynamic types and figure out what they really are.

Comment: But dynamic is the type of the *variable* still, in the same way that if you declare "object x = new MemoryStream()" then the type of the variable is "object" whereas the type of the object the variable's value refers to is "MemoryStream".

Comment: I am trying to find the place where I read in MS lit that explained what I was trying to explain. I can't find it again. I've read too much info from PDC in the past two days.

Comment: Actually, "dynamic" is the type of the variable.  The object's underlying type is some (static) CLR type.  It's only the method dispatch that's dynamic.

Comment: If `dynamic` is the type of the variable then this should compile, right? dynamic x = GetDynamic(); var y = x; // y is also dynamic

Comment: @dalle: Yes, I believe that should be fine. I haven't tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet from the book "CLR via C#, 3rd Ed" shows dynamic in action :

```
using System;
using System.Dynamic;
static class DyanmicDemo
{
    public static void Main() {
  for(Int32 demo =0; demo < 2; demo++) {
   dynamic arg = (demo == 0) ? (dynamic) 5 : (dynamic) "A";
   dynamic result = Plus(arg);
   M(result);
  }
 }
    private static dynamic Plus(dynamic arg) { return arg + arg; }
    private static void M(Int32 n) { Console.WriteLine("M(Int32): " + n); }
    private static void M(String s) { Console.WriteLine("M(String): " + s); }
}
```

When I execute Main, I get the following output:

M(Int32): 10

M(String): AA